# Iterating over multiple cells with a find function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that has multiple entries. These values match a certain field entry but there is an issue with the entries. They need to iterate with each of the values. Below is a picture of what Im trying to achieve. Below is a picture of the issue Im trying to conquer

| Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S006 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_1 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_2 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_3 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_4 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_5 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_6 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_7 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_8 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_9 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |
| S006_10 | match_against | CD12A_TPE1210 |

I need to match column 1 against column 2, if they do match then column three needs to append its number see below:

```
s006 = CD12A_TPE1210
s006_1 = CD12A_TPE1211
s006_2 = CD12A_TPE1212
```

The Reason I need to match column 1 to column 2 is because Im worried this spreadsheet may have some entries that aren't hard set to s006.

I tried the find and replace function with a COUNTIF/IF statement but I'm struggling to get the matching separated from the replace part.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IF(A2:A<>B2:B,,A2:A&" = "&C2:C)))
```

[image]

### Option 2 - Using Lambda

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C, LAMBDA(a,b,c, IF(a="",,IF(a<>b,,a&" = "&c))))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`MAP`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)

Comment: Does this already have column 3 with iterated values? Im trying to get Column 3 iterated.

Comment: Please, tell me if did it work or not? and share a sample of column2. @MaximilianHallett

Comment: Hey, So it didnt work mainly because it isnt altering the values and saying it cant because the cell it is trying to append has a value in it.

Comment: [img]https://i.imgur.com/SD0IinI.png[/img]